# Finding center coordinate of transformed image in terms of previous coordinate system

Tags: qt, geometry, scaling, coordinate-systems

Apologies for asking this question, but I'm having trouble getting my head around 2D geometry and transforms (probably due to lack of sleep), can't visualize things in my mind's eye. Please could you help.

I'm using Qt and QTransform, although this is largely irrelevant as this is a mathematical problem. I have an image that takes up the whole viewport, I zoom into the image at a point (zoomPos) that is clicked on. I accomplish this with the following transform:

```
zoomTransform.translate(zoomPos.x(), zoomPos.y());
zoomTransform.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
zoomTransform.translate(-zoomPos.x(), -zoomPos.y());
```

What I wish to calculate are the point coordinates of the center of the scaled (zoomed) image in terms of the original (unscaled) coordinate system. Another way of explaining this is: I wish to calculate the point coordinates of the original image that is the center of the scaled (zoomed) image. I hope that makes sense.

I tried using QTransform::map which maps a point to the coordinate system defined by the transform. I think I have to use an inverted zoomTransform (not sure) and am not sure which coordinates to map from.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It should be something like `zoomTransform.inverted().map(QPointF(image.width() / 2, image.height() / 2))`.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, I tried that already but didn't get the answer I expected. It could be that I am doing something else wrong. I will look into it.

Comment: The coordinates were correct. But I was using them in a second function to generate some other values, it was the second function that was wrong. So I had worked out the transform correctly. This will teach me not to code when I'm too tired / stressed! Sometimes I doubt myself, it is useful to have a second opinion. Thanks again.